# MSVCR100.dll CPU load 100%

Tags: java, dll

I start my java program (it creates a fullscreen movie in foreground) on the Windows 7 PC (64 bit, i5 processor). 
Using the Process Explorer I saw that problem in that java.exe creates MSVCR100.dll threads that excessive use CPU.

I'm searching any solutions: remove .dll library from different places in Windows (system32, sysWOW64 folders) and this help to decrease CPU load to 10-20%
but afterwards this library loaded from JDK folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll) and everything begins the same.

I'm also increased Java maximum heap size:

```
-Xmx1024m
```

But it also didn't help.

Can anyone help me with that problem?

Comment: msvcr = microsoft visual C++ runtime. the dll is not the problem. something that's USING the dll is the problem

Comment: There is no code here. You shouldn't need to increase heap size. You probably need to rest your while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured out. Thread dump does't help me, but I use Sampler CPU tab in VisualVM tool. It show me the list of classes that by priority moustly load my CPU PC.